# Unity - Added extra offset in facing target maybe difference between Rotate() vs transform.rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am confused to if using Rotate() and .rotation will conflict with each other.

I am moving a transform to point at a Target automatically with .rotation and when I choose to move manually I use Rotate(). But after I stop manual control and use the automatic mode the transform will be offset with the manual movement I had done. So the Rotate() is adding offset. The manual control no matter what is accurate. The automatic targeting is added an offset after using the manual control.

Here is the code for the Manual Control.

```
xDif = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity.x;
yDif = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity.y;
float zDif = 0; // <-- gets changed with buttons
transformToMove.Rotate(new Vector3(yDif, xDif, zDif));
```

Here is the code for Automatic Targeting

```
/// Returns true if the transform has been successfully oriented to fire at the current target.
private bool TrackTarget(out Vector3 hitPosition, out float hitTime)
{
    hitPosition = Vector3.zero;
    hitTime = -1.0f;
    
    if (!IsTargetValid(currentTarget))
    {
        state = TransformState.NoTarget;
        return false;
    }

    if (!GetFiringDirectionToHitTarget(currentTarget, out Vector3 firingDirection, out hitPosition, out hitTime))
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    Quaternion desiredRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(invertFiringDirection ? -firingDirection : firingDirection);
    Quaternion currentRotation = transformToMove.rotation;
    float maxDeltaAngle = maxRotationDegreesPerSecond * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

transformToMove2.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(
    currentRotation, 
    desiredRotation, 
    maxDeltaAngle
);
```

Comment: `transform.rotation= ...` assigns an **absolute orientation** ... In contrary to `transform.Rotate(...); which **adds** a rotation to the current orientation

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html vs https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html By reading these carefully you will have the answer. I don't want the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it was a “stupid” bug. In my manual control, I was applying the rotation to `transformToMove` and in the Editor it was applied to a child of the parent transform. So obviously there was going to be an offset if the initial rotation is for the parent (`transformToMove2`).

Sorry about this, I will leave the post up to teach Unity and even programmers in the future. That no matter how many times you look over your code and refactor it, the solution can be right in front of your eyes. For example, using the wrong transform.....

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `desiredRotation` variable is being influenced by the current rotation of the player.  Your `desiredRotation` is being set based on the `LookRotation()` of a `firingDirection`. Is your `GetFiringDirectionToHitTarget()` method using the player's current position, by chance?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not great at vector math.  I looked it over and didn't see where you're going wrong.  Hopefully someone else can help you more :/